# Is there an equivalent chromium extension for Image Toolbar Firefox Add-ons?

Tags: browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

Still using firefox because can't find Image Toolbar add-ons for Chrome / Chromium.

For those who don't know what Image toolbar is: it is providing toolbar on mouse hover displaying icon for saving image with simply one click. Or ... it's built in feature in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked the Image Toolbar-Addon in Firefox, so I decided to try to create my own extension for this. Maybe you can check it out and give some feedback.

#### [Image-Toolbar (beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpgaepnhfockgofcejphihfafgmenofb)